# Adding a command to all existing Jailkit jails

Tags: ssh, jail, jailkit

I am running [Jailkit](https://olivier.sessink.nl/jailkit/jailkit.8.html) on my server and need to add Mercurial (command `hg`) to all existing and future Jailkit jails.

From what I understand, creating a new jail with `jk_init` and a profile that includes `hg` will only make it available in new jails. How can I add the `hg` command to all my existing jails?

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is the jk_cp command.
E.g. use
jk_cp -j /var/www/clients/client2/web16 /usr/bin/hg
to copy the needed file(s).

Comment: Thanks. This is documented here: https://olivier.sessink.nl/jailkit/jk_cp.8.html